# Error during template compile of 'AppModule' Expression form not supported in angular 5

Tags: angular5

when I trying to create build of my project it shows above error.Instead of specifying the path I am using reg-expression as a matcher for routing in my app.module.

**app.module**

```
{       
        matcher: ComplexUrlMatcher("luxury-cruises/x-to-x-x", /^luxury-cruises\/[a-zA-Z-]+-to-[a-zA-Z-]+-[0-9-]+$/),
        component: RcycVoyagesComponent
    },
  {     
        matcher: ComplexUrlMatcher("luxury-x-cruises", /^luxury-[a-zA-Z-]+-cruises$/),
        component: RcycRegionComponent
    },  
    {
        matcher: ComplexUrlMatcher("luxury-x-cruises/cruises-from-x-x", /^luxury-[a-zA-Z-]+-cruises\/cruises-from-[a-zA-Z-]+-[a-zA-Z-]+$/),
        component: RcycPortsComponent
    },
    {
        matcher: ComplexUrlMatcher("luxury-x-cruises/cruises-from-x-x/porttabs", /^luxury-[a-zA-Z-]+-cruises\/cruises-from-[a-zA-Z-]+-[a-zA-Z-]+\/[a-zA-Z-]+$/),
        component: RcycPortsComponent
    },
    {
        matcher: ComplexUrlMatcher("experience/suites/porttabs", /experience\/suites\/[a-zA-Z-]+$/),
        component: RcycSuitesComponent
    },
```